# Google mock overload resolution

Tags: c++, googletest, overload-resolution, googlemock

I'm using Google Mock to Unit Test. I want the ability to switch between fake and mock.
This is the Fake.

```
class Fake {
public:
    void test(char val1, int val2) {
    }
};
```

And here's the Mock.

```
class Mock {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD2(func, void(int, char*));
    MOCK_METHOD2(func, void(char, int));

    void delegate() {
      ON_CALL(*this, func).WillByDefault([this](char val1, int val2) {
        fake_medusa_->test(val1, val2);
      })
    }

private:
    Fake *fake_;
};
```

The error message is: `error: call to member function 'gmock_func' is ambiguous`

Does someone know what's the method to achieve overload here?

Comment: Not sure why delegating the call to the mock to the fake/stub? With GMock you can set expectations on the calls to the mock, set return values, side effects and custom actions like calling other user-defined methods etc. What's your use case?

Comment: Can't test it right now, but maybe you just can get away with `ON_CALL(*this, func(A<char>(),A<int>())).W...` (just did something similar in my code)

Answer (score 1):

I think that one thing is missing: the `Mock` class should most probably derive from a pure virtual class, but that's a different story.

The ambiguous call error is raised because the compiler doesn't know which `func` method you're referring to in `ON_CALL`. Try this trick of dispatching the call to difderent method::

```
class Mock {
public:
    void func(int i, char* cp) {
        func_int_charp(i, cp);
    }

    void func(char c, int i) {
        func_char_int(c, i);
    }

    MOCK_METHOD2(func_int_charp, void(int, char*));
    MOCK_METHOD2(func_char_int, void(char, int));

    void delegate() {
      ON_CALL(*this, func_char_int).WillByDefault([this](char val1, int val2) {
        fake_medusa_->test(val1, val2);
      })
    }

private:
    Fake *fake_;
};
```

This should do the trick. You can also use typed any matchers :`A<type>`, `An<type>` or typed `Eq` matcher: `TypedEq<type>` or `Matcher<type>`. to disambiguate which `func` method you  on the caller site:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mock_obj, func(A<char>(), TypedEq<int>(10));
```